# Looping through jQuery objects with each and evaluating a condition

Tags: javascript, jquery

I create the very simple script below, in which I came with a question that I can't seem to find in the [.each() documentation](https://api.jquery.com/each/). As you see I would like to loop through a collection of jQuery objects and return either `true` or `false` (if one is false then the .each loop would break so the end result would be false)

For some reason the validation does not seem to work properly.

```js
 $('.with-validation').on('submit', function (e) {
   if (isValid()) {
     console.log('validation succeded');
     return true;
   } else {
     console.log('validation failed');
     return false;
   }
 });
    
function isValid () {
  var $required = $('.required');
  var $emails = $('.email');
  var inputsValidation = function () {
    return $(this).val().length > 0;
  }
  $required.each(inputsValidation);
  return inputsValidation;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <form class="with-validation">
        <input name="lastname" class="required" type="text"></input>
        <input name="firstname" type="text"></input>
        <input name="phone" class="required" type="text"></input>
        <input name="email" class="required email" type="text"></input>
        <input name="confEmail" class="required email" type="text"></input>
        <button class="submit-btn" type="submit">OK</button>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Could you provide more information? are there any errors?

Comment: What's the point of `validateEmail()` if it just returns `true`?

Comment: `.each` just iterates over a jquery collection. It **does not return** any value. If you want to use `.each` in your case you have to define external boolean flag and change it inside `.each`.

Comment: @HristiyanDodov none really, I'll remove it to not complicate things. (it's a reduced use-case)

Comment: @FabioAntunes you can run the snippet - the submit event shouldn't be triggered unless there's text in every "required" input field.

Comment: @hindmost can you provide an answer? (.each is not a requirement, any efficient way acceptable) (although I'd like to see how it'd work with each)

Comment: I strongly suggest you stop trying to create your own validation framework. Use this instead: https://jqueryvalidation.org/

Comment: @Emyr by no means I would ever do that/doing that now, this is in the context of exploring the language and research. I would though like to understand the mechanics of `.each`.

Comment: @Downvoter : please explain your vote. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Array.prototype.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) if your function is looking for ***valid condition***. Or use [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) with a function checking for ***invalid condition***. (*Use a polyfill if you support < IE9*)

Use [`.toArray`](https://api.jquery.com/toArray/) to convert `jQuery` collection to an Array.

You are comparing the two functions itself `inputsValidation && emailsValidation` and not the result, also `$each` doesn't return result that way. Get the results to some variables and compare the results, not the function itself.

```js
$('.with-validation').on('submit', function (e) {
   if (isValid()) {
     console.log('validation succeded');
     return true;
   } else {
     console.log('validation failed');
     return false;
   }
 });
    
function isValid () {
  var $required = $('.required').toArray();
  var $emails = $('.email').toArray();
  var emailsValidation = function (i) {
    return validateEmail(i.value);
  }
  var inputsValidation = function (i) {
    return i.value.length > 0;
  }

  var condition1 = $emails.every(emailsValidation);
  var condition2 = $required.every(inputsValidation);
  return condition1 && condition2;
}

function validateEmail(email) {
  return true;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <form class="with-validation">
        <input name="lastname" class="required" type="text"></input>
        <input name="firstname" type="text"></input>
        <input name="phone" class="required" type="text"></input>
        <input name="email" class="required email" type="text"></input>
        <input name="confEmail" class="required email" type="text"></input>
        <button class="submit-btn" type="submit">OK</button>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: good one. Thank you for using native methods for this:) I guess we might as well dump jQuery all together and select the elements with vanilla JS..

Answer (score 1):

jQuery unfortunately doesn't offer a method to filter for the first hit. ( `.filter` will find all that match). That's is why I made this small jQuery extension method, which will return the first element that doesn't match the filter.

```
$.fn.extend({
  firstMismatch: function(filter) {
    for(var element, i = 0; element = this[i]; i++) 
      if(!filter.call(element)) return element;
  }
});
```

Now to validate all input fields you simply have to call it like this. How does it work? `$required.firstMismatch(inputsValidation)` will return the first element that doesn't match the filter. So if it doesn't return any element, all match. The `!` will inverse the returned value, so that no element returns true

```
  return !$required.firstMismatch(inputsValidation)  
      && !$emails.firstMismatch(emailsValidation)
```

This approach as has few benefits: you can do it in a single line, it checks only until one fails ( even prevents checking the mail at all if the `required` don't validate) and it gives you the option `this` to use.

`.firstMismatch()` can also be used for other things

#### solution

```js
$('.with-validation').on('submit', function(e) {
  if (isValid()) {
    console.log('validation succeded');
    return true;
  } else {
    console.log('validation failed');
    return false;
  }
});

function isValid() {
  var $required = $('.required');
  var $emails = $('.email');
  
  var emailsValidation = function () {
    return validateEmail($(this).val());
  }
  
  var inputsValidation = function () {
    return $(this).val().length > 0;
  }

  return !$required.firstMismatch(inputsValidation) 
      && !$emails.firstMismatch(emailsValidation)

}

function validateEmail(email) {
  return true;
}

$.fn.extend({
  firstMismatch: function(filter) {
    for (var element, i = 0; element = this[i]; i++)
      if (!filter.call(element)) return element;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <form class="with-validation">
        <input name="lastname" class="required" type="text"/>
        <input name="firstname" type="text"/>
        <input name="phone" class="required" type="text"/>
        <input name="email" class="required email" type="text"/>
        <input name="confEmail" class="required email" type="text"/>
        <button class="submit-btn" type="submit">OK</button>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: `vailedInput` contains the length of all the valid input fields and  `$required.length` contains the original length of all the arrays. Now you have to compare these two, if they match - all fields are valid. the 3 `=` just make sure the typ matches as well, but it's not strictly necessary. The same goes for the email.

Comment: `.filter` doesn't provide option to break the loop. It will run test callback for **each** element of collection even if test test fails on the first one.

Comment: @hindmost that's true. I'll think of a better solution

Comment: @GeorgeKatsanos indeed. I made an update, with what I believe, is the cleanest solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I changed a bit of your script, Hope this is what your "looking" for

I also change your "submit" trigger to allow you to run the example here.
You should be able to use `$('form.with-validation').on('submit',function(){})`

```js
$('.with-validation button').on('click', function() {
  if (isValid() == true) {
    console.log('validation succeded');
    return true;
  } else {
    console.log('validation failed');
    return false;
  }
});

function isValid() {
  var isvalid = true;
  $('.required').each(function() {
    if (isvalid) {
      if ($(this).hasClass("email")) {
        if (!validateEmail($(this).val())) {
          isvalid = false
        }

      } else {
        if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
          isvalid = false
        }
      }
    }
  })
  return isvalid
}


function validateEmail(emailAddress) {
  var pattern = new RegExp(/^(("[\w-\s]+")|([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)|("[\w-\s]+")([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*))(@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$)|(@\[?((25[0-5]\.|2[0-4][0-9]\.|1[0-9]{2}\.|[0-9]{1,2}\.))((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\.){2}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\]?$)/i);
  return pattern.test(emailAddress);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <form class="with-validation">
    <input name="lastname" class="required" placeholder="lastname" type="text"></input>
    <input name="firstname" type="text" placeholder="firstname"></input>
    <input name="phone" class="required" type="text" placeholder="phone"></input>
    <input name="email" class="required email" type="text" placeholder="email"></input>
    <input name="confEmail" class="required email" type="text" placeholder="confEmail"></input>
    <button class="submit-btn" type="submit">OK</button>
  </form>
</body>
```